# Show that $\{|f''(z_0)|: f\in \mathcal{F}\}$ is a closed set for a compact family $ \mathcal{F}$ of holomorphic functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I have the following problem:

> Let $\mathcal{F}\neq \emptyset$ be a compact family of holomorphic functions in a domain $U$, that is, every $f_n\in \mathcal{F}$ has a locally uniformly convergent subsequence whose limit also belongs to $ \mathcal{F}$.
>
> Let $z_0\in U$. Show that there is a function $f_0\in \mathcal{F}$ such that $|f_0''(z_0)|=\sup \{|f''(z_0)|:f\in \mathcal{F}\}$.

---

My attempt:

I only can prove that $\{f''(z):f\in \mathcal{F}\}$ is also compact. Since the statement is about "subsequence", I think it is far away from the desired conclusion.

Also, the limit function $f$ of $f_n''$ may not be the one which can achieve the maximum of $|f''(z_0)|$ for some $z_0\in U$.

Comment: "that is, every $f_n\in \mathcal{F}$" I don't think that's what you mean

Comment: He means: every sequence $(f_n)$ in $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Continuous functions (here: $f\mapsto f''(z_0)$) on compact sets attain their supremum.

Comment: There is a notion of continuous functional $J$ on any family of holomorphic functions in a domain, which is defined by the condition that for every sequence $(f_n)$ of functions from the family normally converging in the domain, one has $J(f_n)\rightarrow J(f)$. Clearly, for any $k\in \mathbb N$ and from any point $z_0$ in the domain, the functional given by $f\mapsto f^{(k)}(z_0)$ is continuous by the Weierstrass theorem. You can easily show that if $J$ is a continuous functional on a compact family of holomorphic functions in a domain, then $|J|$ attains its supremum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S:=\sup \{|f''(z_0)|:f\in \mathcal{F}\}$. Then there is a sequence $(f_n)$ in $\mathcal{F}$ such that

$(1)$ $|f_n''(z_0)| \to S$.

$(f_n)$ has a locally uniformly convergent subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ whose limit $f$ also belongs to $\mathcal{F}$ .

The Convergence Theorem of Weierstraß says:

$(f_{n_k}'')$ converges locally uniformly to $f''$. Hence

$(2)$ $|f_n''(z_0)| \to |f''(z_0)|$.

From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get

$$S=|f''(z_0)|.$$